# How to validate URLs in CakePHP 3.x?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

how can I validate a valid URL that has been entered in a form field
before saving it to a database table say for example "links" table ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: use php function for this `filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)`

Comment: Short answer is Regexp

Comment: Or use `'rule' => 'url'`  
eg `public $validate = array(
    'website' => array(
        'rule' => 'url'
    )
);` Ref: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation::url

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `src/Model/Table/[YourClasses]Table.php`

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator) {
    // In with the other validators
    $validator->add('url', 'valid', ['rule' => 'url']);

    return $validator;
}
```

The Validator default options are available here:

http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Validation.Validation.html#_url

Answer (score 1):

something like this: haven't tested it so may need a bit of a tweak..

```
  function check_url($url)
  { 
 $url = preg_match_all('#[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~\#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~\#?&//=]*)?#si', $url);
       return $url;
   }
```